# Encrypting a programs internal code [c#]

Tags: c#, .net

as the title says, I am wondering how you would encrypt the code inside of a project, more specifically a C# .net application, I don't want other people using various things like '.NET reflector' and getting the 'source' from my program, any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: Look up Obfuscation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977082(v=vs.107).aspx

Comment: Obfuscation was the word I was looking for, Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

There has to be a way to do so, because the code itself is kind of interpreted when run. Therefore you cant hide it completely, as this would prevent your program from running.
However there is a List of obfuscators which 'scramble' your code to make it hard to understand for humans, you can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET).
However this will not make your code completely safe and someone who really wants your code could still get it.
If you absolutely need unreadable code you should choose a language wich compiles to machine code, but even there are still ways.